# BadRequest: load GeoDataFrame to bigquery PYTHON

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, upload

I'm trying to export a GeoDataFrame to Bigquery, but I'm getting the following error: BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Invalid geography value for column 'geometry', error: Polygon's first loop must be shell. It is nested in loop 2; in WKB geography

The problem is a specific row. What I can do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpKs0.png)

The Geodataframe have this structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2WJi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the geometry data for this row?

This error might be a real invalid data, or it might be caused by wrong polygon's loop orientation. See this for discussion of polygon loops orientation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#polygon_orientation

When the data is loaded as WKB/WKT, BigQuery treats the data as oriented, while many planar-oriented geometry libraries don't care much about polygon orientation, which might cause this error.

The possible solutions if the cause is orientation:

- Fix polygon loops orientation
- Load using GeoJson format, rather than WKT (GeoJson is planar geometry format, so while the standard specifies loop orientation, it is not mandatory)
- Load as string (with WKT content), then convert it to Geography in BigQuery using [st_geogfromtext](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogfromtext) function. By default the function treats input as non-oriented, unless `oriented => true` parameter is passed.